# Errors with poemscol

Tags: poetry

Running into errors with poemscol. When I run the script below I get the following errors (just a sample)

Undefined control sequence. \fancyhfoffset

Missing \begin{document}. \fancyoffset[

etc.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,makeidx,times,multicol,geometry}
\usepackage{keyval,ifthen,mparhack,manyfoot,poemscol}

\begin{document}
    \leftheader{Pandemic Haiku}

    \poemtitle{ Haiku 1 (20200326) }
        \begin{poem}
            The silence is big, but \\
        \verseindent    Spaces not big enough. \\
            Masks of fear hide smiles 
        \end{poem}


    \poemtitle{  Haiku 2}
    \begin{poem}
        The world seems empty; \\
        \verseindent The sky is full of wonder \\
        Moonlight fills the night.
    \end{poem}

    \poemtitle{ Haiku 3}
    \begin{poem}
    Now Absurdity \\
    \verseindent Fills the whole world with Chaos. \\
    Where does it find you? 
    \end{poem}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: updated distribution to texlive and rec'd the following error:

```
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/poemscol/poemscol.sty
Writing index file PandemicHaiku.idx
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/poemscol/poemscol.sty:489: Undefin
ed control sequence.
l.489 \fancyhfoffset
                    [RO,LE]{\headoffsetlength}
?
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Runs without any error or warning here on texlive 2020!

Comment: Runs also fine on an older TeX Live 2017.

Comment: Dang... I'm running TeXstudio 2.12.22. There must be a difference in the default packages.  I updated everything using %sudo tlmgr update --all

Comment: Also compiles fine on my system, which is TeXlive 2019.

Comment: I see that others have gotten it to compile on TexLive 2020. Is there a package that i may have forgotten/misinstalled?